# issue in which variables cannot be updated by v-model after adding a key to an object in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object

There is a value stored in json format in the existing db,
so I want to add select to this value and bind it to v-model

But like the below, the value is not being updated normally
Can I ask for help on this matter??

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    options: [{
        "vals": ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
      },
      {
        "vals": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
      }
    ]
  },

  created() {
    this.init_options();
  },

  methods: {
    init_options() {
      $.each(this.options, function(option_index, option) {
        option.select = [];
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#root > div {
  border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  padding:15px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div v-for="(option, option_key) in options">
    <div v-for="(val, val_key) in option.vals">
     <input  type="checkbox"
             :value="val"
             :name="'name['+option_key+']'"
             :id="'id['+option_key+'_'+val_key+']'"
             v-model="option.select">
     <label :for="'id['+option_key+'_'+val_key+']'">{{val}}</label>
    </div>
    select value : {{option.select}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please check the reactivity of your variable. If you add a new key in your object then vue will not add it in the change detection mechanism by itself. You will have to tell vue to add it by using Object.assign(). For more read this official document https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: I would say add the select key while declaring options in data

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan I'll check the link you sent me. Thank you for your kind answer 

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan I solved the problem via this.$set instance method
Thank you for taking me out of hell over hours.
Have a nice day :->

Comment: Anytime..... :)